# Mac osx Lion - Create lion dvd from preinstalled macbook

Tags: osx-lion

How can I make an installation dvd if the os was already preinstalled on my new macbook? I have seen a method of doing this but requires purchasing a copy of lion in the app store.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

You log in to the mac app store with the apple account connected with the purchase of the mac book, download the lion installer and use [DiskMakerX](http://diskmakerx.com) to create a bootable thumb drive...

I'm afraid there is no way to create an installation medium from an already installed system. No OS known to me supports this feature.

Alternatively you can get hold of an OS X bootable disk image from any apple account that has purchased it and use a Macs disk utility to burn it to a dvd.